# Disassemblers resolving (ELF) section names

Tags: disassembly, linux, elf

I'm working with linux executables and was just wondering how it is that section names are resolved to addresses upon disassembly of an ELF.

For example take some random disassembly output from objdump,

```
  4002b5:       00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  4002b7:       00 67 55                add    %ah,0x55(%rdi)
  4002ba:       61                      (bad)  
  4002bb:       10                      .byte 0x10

Disassembly of section .dynsym:

00000000004002c0 <.dynsym>:
        ...
  4002d8:       9b                      fwait
  4002d9:       00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  4002db:       00 12                   add    %dl,(%rdx)
        ...
  4002ed:       00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  4002ef:       00 32                   add    %dh,(%rdx)
  4002f1:       00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  4002f3:       00 12                   add    %dl,(%rdx)
        ...
  400305:       00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  400307:       00 17                   add    %dl,(%rdi)
```

how has it, if from a heuristic perspective, detected that the section at that address is called dynsm? The same goes for .text, .bss, and even functions listed by objdump, such as 'main'.

How would I reproduce this if I were to write a disassembly tool + executable analyser myself?

Thanks

Comment: For ELF binary files, the compiler inserts debug information such as function names, source lines, ... using a debug format called DWARF. The disassembler doesn't guess the name, it reads it from the DWARF info associated to an assembly block/section. check out the documentation : http://www.dwarfstd.org/. Also, the answer below covers only sections - it is incomplete.

Comment: @yaspr this question is specifically about how to retrieve section information. It is not about debugging or functions. DWARF and debug symbols are not relevant in this particular case.

Comment: @yaspr could you verify whether this debug information is inserted by default? Reading into DWARF, and the GCC compiler, GCC does not do this by default (gcc -o).

Comment: @SYS_V : "... and even functions listed by objdump...", it is somehow relevant but as I said, your answer is thorough and the DWARF is only complementary with some magic.

Comment: @Marius.pharoe DWARF info are not there by default, but they are very helpful (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html).

Comment: @yaspr DWARF information, while potentially useful, is not required to determine function names and offsets. This information is preserved in the symbol table (.`symtab`) in `STT_FUNC` entries. Unlike DWARF data, the symbol table is included in the binary by GCC by default.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the in example in the question, data is being disassembled as code. [The `.dynsym` section holds the dynamic linking symbol table and does not contain code](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2539/what-symbol-tables-stay-after-a-strip-in-elf-format).

---

- Information such as the name and the virtual address of the first byte of a section is given in the *section header* of that section.
- The section header is a structure stored in the *section header table* of an ELF binary.

In this case `objdump` prints the virtual address `00000000004002c0` and the name `.dynsym` because this is the information stored in the section header for that particular section (technically, section names are strings stored in the section header string table `.shstrtab`, but this is not so important in this case). If there was no section header for this section or if there was no section header table present in the binary, `objdump` would not be able to output this information.

There is no need for heuristics unless the section header table is not present in the binary. This is unusual, but has been observed to be the case in certain Linux ELF binaries (viruses) in order to thwart analysis since `gdb`, `objdump`, and other [Binary File Descriptor-based utilities](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/bfd-2.9.1/html_mono/bfd.html) (thank you Igor Skochinsky for the correction) rely on information in the section header table to parse the binary.

Relevant documentation can be found in the [System V ABI (generic)](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/elf/gabi41.pdf) beginning in chapter 4 "Object Files" (page 44), as well as the [manual page for ELF](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html).

> A *section header table* contains information describing the file’s sections. Every section has an entry in the table; each
>   entry gives information such as the section name, the section size, and so on.

More specifically:

> An object file’s section header table lets one locate all the file’s sections. The section header table is an array of `Elf32_Shdr` or
>   `Elf64_Shdr` structures. A section header table index is a subscript into this array. The ELF header’s `e_shoff` member gives the byte offset from the beginning of the file to the section header table; `e_shnum` tells how many entries the section header table contains; `e_shentsize` gives the size in bytes of each entry.

Additionally,

> Sections contain all information in an object file, except the ELF header, the program header table, and the section header table. Moreover, object files’ sections satisfy several conditions.
>
> - Every section in an object file has exactly one section header describing it. Section headers may exist that do not have a section.
> - Each section occupies one contiguous (possibly empty) sequence of bytes within a file.
> - Sections in a file may not overlap. No byte in a file resides in more than one section.
> - An object file may have inactive space. The various headers and the sections might not ‘‘cover’’ every byte in an object file. The contents of the inactive data are unspecified.

Here is a high-level overview of what is involved in locating information contained in an ELF binary's individual section headers. The documentation cited is for ELF32 binaries, but the process is the same with ELF64 binaries.

The location of the section header table is given in the ELF header:

[image: ELF header location]

The ELF header is a struct and the offset of the section header table is stored in a member called `e_shoff`:

[image: ELF header structure and members]

[image: e_shoff]

```
$ readelf -h /bin/ls
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF64
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           Advanced Micro Devices X86-64
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x404890
  Start of program headers:          64 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          108288 (bytes into file)   <---------- e_shoff
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           56 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         9
  Size of section headers:           64 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         28
  Section header string table index: 27
```

The section header table is usually located at the end of the binary following all of the sections:

[image: section header table location in binary]

As stated in the documentation and mentioned previously, every section has an entry in the section header table. Each entry is a structure that contains information about the section, including its name and its virtual address when the binary is mapped into memory. The name of the section is stored in a struct member called `sh_name`, and the address information is stored in a struct member called `sh_addr`:

[image: section header structure]

[image: sh_name]

[image: sh_addr]

Retrieving this information is just a matter of correctly parsing these structures within a given binary.

More information can be found here:

- [The ELF Object File Format: Introduction](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/1059)
- [The ELF Object File Format by Dissection](http://www.linuxjournal.com/node/1060/print)

Comment: Thorough explanation yet incomplete given it only covers sections. The DWARF or debug symbols aren't cited and to be honest, that's where the magic happens.

Comment: in fact, `readelf` works fine on files without section headers (unlike BFD-based `objdump` or `gdb`)

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky Thank you, corrected. If there are any other errors, please let me know.