# Elf file format finding .got and .got.plt segments

Tags: static-analysis, elf, disassemblers

I'm writing ELF parser and simple disassembler x86. Having code like this

```
.text:000B5A2A      call 0000B470 ;e.g. _glXSwapBuffers
...
...
got.plt:0000B470    jmp     dword ptr [ebx+240h] ;jump to .got@_glXSwapBuffers
```

I wonder how can I recognize **.got**, **.got.plt** segments at ELF parsing time ? Simple way is to just check the segment \ section name but this can be fooled easily.

Anyone knows what's the proper way to identify **.got**, **.got.plt** segments \ sections during ELF file format parsing ?

Answer (score 1):

`.got` and `.got.plt` are examples of labels that will always describe sections and never segments.

There is a critical conceptual difference between sections and segments. Sections provide information about how information is organized within a binary, and segments describe to the program loader (and if the binary is dynamically linked, the dynamic linker) how a process image should be composed in virtual memory from the binary. Take a look at the SysV ABI (generic) and the output of `readelf -SW -l <binary>` for more on the difference between sections and segments.

Information about sections is stored in the section header table, so to find information about sections in a binary, parse the section header table. Note that the section header table is not required to be present in the binary - the loader only uses segment information to accomplish process creation.

Familiarize yourself with ELF structure by exploring this excellent diagram: https://github.com/corkami/pics/blob/master/binary/elf101/elf101-64.pdf

See [Disassemblers resolving (ELF) section names](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16829/disassemblers-resolving-elf-section-names/16830#16830) for more about the section header table.

Comment: thanks for answer and clarifying section vs segment but it's not exactly what I was asking about.

Comment: the answer to your question is parse the section header table, as I said. See https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16829/disassemblers-resolving-elf-section-names/16830#16830