# How does a stripped XCOFF binary still remain usable?

Tags: file-format

IBM's AIX [`strip`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds5/strip.htm) utility documentation states the following:

> The strip command with no options removes the line number information,
>   relocation information, symbol table, the debug section, and the
>   typchk section, and the comment section.

If relocation information is removed, how come the stripped executable still remain usable?

Comment: Okay, that‘s weird. Without relocation information, the binary either has to be position independent code or cannot be ASLRed. I‘m looking forward to the answer.

Comment: That's not exactly a reverse engineering question, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

COFF files were not designed to support relocation after link-time:

> The binary format used initially for Linux was an `a.out`
>   variant. **When introducing shared libraries certain design
>   decisions had to be made to work in the limitations of
>   `a.out`. The main accepted limitation was that no *relocations* are performed at the time of loading and afterward.
>   The shared libraries have to exist in the form they are
>   used at run-time on disk.** This imposes a major restriction on the way shared libraries are built and used: every
>   shared library must have a fixed load address; otherwise it
>   would not be possible to generate shared libraries which
>   do not have to be relocated.<sup>1</sup>

While XCOFF represents an extension of COFF that does support use of shared libraries, the relocation information removed by `strip` pertains to information used for link-time relocation rather than load- or run-time relocation:

- > Reduces the size of an Extended Common Object File Format (XCOFF) object file by removing information used by the binder and symbolic debug program.
- > The binder uses the relocation information to modify address constants and other relocatable values when individual XCOFF object files are linked to create an XCOFF executable file.<sup>2</sup>

The binder appears to play a role similar to that of the link editor [`ld`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html) on Linux systems.

See the description of the `-x` flag:

> Removes the symbol table information but does not remove static or external symbol information. **The -x flag also removes relocation information, therefore linking to the file would not be possible.**

---

1. [How to Write Shared Libraries](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/a/1/e/dsohowto.pdf)
2. [Relocation Information for XCOFF File (reloc.h)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.files/XCOFF.htm#XCOFF__sua3i125jbau)

Answer (score 2):

apparently the [XCOFF format](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.files/XCOFF.htm)  has a separate section for dynamic linker (*system loader*):

> ## Loader Section (loader.h)
>
> The loader section contains information required by the system loader
> to load and relocate an executable XCOFF object. The loader section is
> generated by the binder. The loader section has an s_flags section
> type flag of STYP_LOADER in the XCOFF section header. By convention,
> .loader is the loader section name. The data in this section is not
> referenced by entries in the XCOFF symbol table.

Presumably this one is not removed by `strip`, so the file still works.

See also similar question on what happens with [stripped ELF files](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2539/what-symbol-tables-stay-after-a-strip-in-elf-format).